# Alternate row color

Tags: jasper-reports, report, ireport

I am using *JasperReport* as a reporting tool for Web Application. (JSP + Servlets)

I have developed a sample report using *iReport*, in which I wants to set alternate color for rows.

I have taken a *frame* in *Detail* Band with following properties:

- **setOpaque**=*true*
- **backcolor**=*grey*
- **Print when expression** = *`new Boolean( $V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue() % 2
  ==0)`*

Then I have taken a *TextField* in *Detail* Band with following properties:

- *setOpaque*=false

[image]

Now when I run this report from *iReport*, it gives correct output in *PDF* format, but when it executes in *HTML* format in the browser, then it doesn't shows the grey color on the alternate lines.

**Update 1:** 
If I select preview as *XHTML Preview* then it shows the desired output in the web browser too. So there is no problem of browser compatibility. So what might be the reason for not displaying correctly as *HTML Preview*?

So please let me know if I am missing some trick here.

Comment: see http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514828/alternate-row-color

Comment: @AnilBharadia Thanks for the link, but I have seen lots of question on jspersoft community and on SO, and on some other sites using google, but still I can't find the solution for the problem, i might be missing some small trick here.

Comment: try different browser

Comment: @AnilBharadia I have tried three browsers, `1: IE`, `2: Chrome`, `3: Firefox`, but it doesn't work on any of them

Comment: @Bhushan: Show a simple example. Create a JRXML file that illustrates the problem and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering why **Print when expression** : new Boolean( $V{**PAGE_COUNT**}.intValue() % 2 == 0).  I think it should be ($V{**REPORT_COUNT**} % 2) == 0.  I tested with HTML preview and able to see a grey rectangle shows and hides alternately.

Comment: can we toggle the opaque like this ?